# Double Fourier Series (external satellite resonance)

Tags: fourier-series, celestial-mechanics

I'm working through a paper "Dynamics of Planetary Rings" by Goldreich and Tremaine (http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev.aa.20.090182.001341). I'm working through p.22 about expanding the potential of an external satellite as a double Fourier series. The external satellite is in epicyclic oscillation with coordinates given by $r = a(1 - ecos(\kappa t))$ and $\theta = \Omega t + \frac{2\Omega e}{\kappa} sin(\kappa t)$ (these can be found in p.2 of http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu//full/1980ApJ...241..425G/0000426.000.html). $\kappa$ is the epicyclic frequency and $\Omega$ is the circular orbital frequency at $r=a$.

I'm struggling to see how to the lowest order in e the eccentricity of the satellite, the first coefficient (m,0) is given as that in the paper.